# Nested form not complaining, but not saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, nested

the forms for creating my polls show up correctly and the poll itself is created, but the answer options are not saved...

I am using rails 5.0.0.1

this is my db :

```
class CreatePolls < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :polls do |t|
      t.string :question

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
class CreateAnswerOptions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :answer_options do |t|
      t.references :poll, foreign_key: true
      t.string :text
      t.integer :nbvotes, :default => 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

-

my models :

```
class AnswerOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poll
end
```

-

```
class Poll < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answer_options, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_options
end
```

my controller :

```
  # GET /polls/new
  def new
    @poll = Poll.new
    2.times { @poll.answer_options.build }
  end

  # POST /polls
  # POST /polls.json
  def create
    @poll = Poll.new(poll_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @poll.save
        format.html { redirect_to @poll, notice: 'Poll was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @poll }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @poll.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and my view :

```
<%= form_for(poll) do |f| %>
  <% if poll.errors.any? %>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(poll.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this poll from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% poll.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.label :question %>
      <%= f.text_field :question, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <!--tab-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11">
      <label for="options">Options</label>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <%= f.fields_for :answer_options do |builder|%>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= builder.text_field :text %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Create Poll", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I can't find why the data is not being saved... I can create them in the rails console ans they get displayed in the show action. I tried playing with adding and removing 's' in the naming of poll or answer_option without success...

Comment: Could you please post your `create` method in the controller? Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: In your view, form_for should have an instance of Poll class that you have created in new method of PollController.,  that is; form_for(@poll).

Comment: Could you show post request from rails console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please use this piece of code. You are required to permit the answer_options_attributes params as it is created by nested attributes automatically.

```
def poll_params
  params.require(:poll).permit(:question, answer_options_attributes: [:text])
end
```